# Problems testing django tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm following the example here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from ristoturisto.api import EntryResource

entry_resource = EntryResource()
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^blog/', include('ristoturisto.urls')), #this basically points to it self?
    (r'^api/', include(EntryResource.urls)),
```

)

api.py

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from locations.models import tours


class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = tours.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'Tours'
```

Models:

```
class tours(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ForeignKey('categories')
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publishdate = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('geolocations')
```

The error i get is:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/tours

When i try to access: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tours?format=json`

Where does Entity_resource get it's URL's from? It's not in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the class *EntryResource* instead of the instance of this class **entry_resource**:

```
(r'^api/', include(EntryResource.urls)),
```

change it:

```
(r'^api/', include(entry_resource.urls)),
```

Comment: By god you are right! I have a new error now but thank you was stuch with that for 2 days... You sir are a true gentleman!

Comment: Do you use any code checker? I use flake8 and it notifies me in cases like this (e.g. the variable is unused). https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8